# Asus VivoBook S14 S410UF touchpad buttons do not work

Tags: laptop, drivers, touchpad, asus-laptop

Asus VivoBook S14 S410UF touchpad buttons do not work.

What can I do about the problem?

I tried to uninstall the current driver and installing the driver from the official site: https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-S14-S410UF/HelpDesk_Download/. It did not help.

And I never see the actualy touchpad driver in the device manager:
[image]

Another strange thing is that after uninstalling the touchpad driver the touchpad continued to work even after restarting the laptop.

I am lame at understanding the issue, so the question may lack some information, please ask me if you need to know something else in order to help me.

After a little bit of investigation I found out that the driver for touchpad is installed under `Human Interface Devices` -> `ASUS Precision Touchpad`.

[image]

I tried to disable the driver to verify that it is actually responsible for the touchpad and it is (since the touchpad stopped to work). Then when I restart my laptop the driver installs itself on its own and touchpad works again. I tried to update the touchpad driver and roll back the update. Nothing helped, even worse: previously the right click button worked and now it does not work. What else can I try?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From "I tried to uninstall the current driver and installing the driver from the official site " : we can see the touchpad driver before we uninstalling it, **the current driver** is Microsoft driver or Asus driver? We uninstall it from **Mice and other pointing devices** or **Keyboards**?

From "Another strange thing is that after uninstalling the touchpad driver the touchpad continued to work even after restarting the laptop": I think the touchpad driver must be installed by system during the laptop restarts. It is one of the two:

[image]

If we unplug the mouse, there will be only one in **Mice and other pointing devices**, it is the touchpad drive.

If touchpad buttons do not work, maybe it is the touchpad hardware issue, we can go to the manufacturer to check it out.

Comment: Updated my question a little bit. Maybe you will find something useful in the update to help me out of the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Both right click button and left click button do not work？It should be within the ASUS warranty period, it is recommended to contact ASUS after sales.

Comment: Yes, both of them do not work now. Previously it was only left click.